# Dubai 90 Day Visa as EU / Spanish Citizen

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, spanish-citizens

I would like some help to understand my correct situation related to the 90-day visa stay in the UAE in my case in Dubai. I entered the country for the first time in November 2020, and stayed for 30 days. I then flew back to Spain and stayed in Spain for 3 months. I have now come back to Dubai on the 15th of march to stay for some time until I get myself sorted to live here permanently. My question is - I've read online that we have 90-day stay within a 180-day period.

If I visited the country for the first time on the 15th of November 2020, so the period of 180 days from first entry would be until the end of May 2021. I've come back to Dubai on the 15th of March 2021, so would I have to leave the country when my remaining 60 days are over? Or is this considered a new entry for 90 days?

Comment: Assuming works in the same mannor as in the Schengen Area: 2021-05-13 minus 2020-11-15 = 180 days (dates inclusive). How many days within that period in the UAE? 30(nov/dec) +16(march)+30(april)+13(may)=90 days. The 90 days **is not** reset simply because you left around the 15th of December.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's not how the Schengen area rules work, though. If you stayed out of the area for 90 days, you have another 90 day when entering again. Provided the “three months” out of the country are at least 90 days, the length of the earlier stay would be irrelevant. I don't know if the rule in Dubai is the same (the answer suggests it is not).

Comment: @Pavan Did you get an new entry stamp on your latest arrival?

Answer (score 3):

[According to the airline Emirates' website](https://www.emirates.com/nl/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/), "your passport will be stamped with a multiple entry 90-day visit visa that's valid for 6 months from the date of issue, and for a stay of 90 days in total." This probably means that you re-entered on your original visa and that you must leave once you've reached 90 days total between the two trips.